# Meaning of a sentence in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

He’d been dashing out of Chamberlain’s class over and over again for fake bathroom breaks, **bolting down the hallway and out the door, a gust of wind, only to find…nothing.** No monster. No mutant. No madman. Just Brooklyn being Brooklyn, left with a new awkward excuse about what took him so long in the bathroom.

I need someone rewrite this sentence in a easy way i can understand...
Here's what i got: He slammed hallway's door and make wind?

Comment: According to the internet,  "Spider Man can run well over 150 mph but he has not reached his full potential because he doubts himself." Other sites have higher speeds, but it may be safe to assume he can 'blow by' folks like a gust of wind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after having read it in context I'm not certain, but I think the gust of wind was a metaphor for Miles' progress along the hallway. [The Disney book *Miles Morales Spider-Man* by Jason Reynolds](https://books.disney.com/content/uploads/2017/05/MilesMorales-chapters-1_2_update.pdf) is juvenile fiction (and I'm going to leave that as an ambiguity), so ease of reading will have taken precedence over literary form.

I think a simile would have been clearer :

> "..bolting down the hallway and out the door like a gust of wind, only
>   to find…nothing."

[Though I'll agree - the idea of Miles bolting down the corridor and then emitting a gust of wind is much funnier.]

Edit after comment :

[Simile and metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile) are both figures of speech which compare one thing to something else for artistic reasons. Instead of saying "The sky was blue", simile would suggest "The sky was like a pool of water" and metaphor would say "The sky was a pool of water", both giving an impression of something that looked blue, but doing it in a more creative way.

In this case, Miles' progress along the hallway was fast, but rather than saying that Reynolds has compared it to a gust of wind.

Writers try to be too clever for their own good sometimes.

Comment: Thanks but i'm still confused :( Could you pls explain more? cuz i wanna translate it and i want something more clear

Comment: _Because I want to translate it_, please! He ran out of the classroom, down the hall and out of the door. It must mean the external door, since he could see (the district of) Brooklyn when he got outside.